# Unable to locate a dynamically loaded pop up using explicit (Fluent) wait in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am unable to locate a popup that is being displayed dynamically in our website. Initially the element is in the below html state:

```
<div class="notification_container" style = "display: none; overflow: hidden; float: none"
</div>
```

Using jquery's show and hide, the div is being shown for 5 seconds and hidden later.

In my selenium scripts, I am trying tying to wait for the style attribute to change from "display: none" to "display: block" using below statement:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(By.className("notification_container"), "style", "display: block"));
```

Below is my fluent wait declaration:

```
    public void waitForElement(Wait<WebDriver> wait) {
    try {
        if (wait == null) {
                        this.wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(myBrowser)
                            // Timeout time is set to 60
                            .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            // polling interval
                            .pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            // ignore the exception
                            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, ElementNotVisibleException.class);
                          }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(+e.getMessage());
        }
  }
```

However, I get below exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for value to contain "display: block;". Current value: "null" (tried for 60 second(s) with 100 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

**Note:** In addition, I have tried to use below methods in combination of expectedconditions:

1. attributeToBe
2. elementToBeClickable
3. presenceOfElementLocated
4. visibilityOfElementLocated

All of them fail with timeout exception. Any help / pointing in right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to `locate the popup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than waiting for a specific attribute, I would suggest that you just wait for the element to be visible ... that's basically what you are trying to do anyway. It's already available in `ExpectedConditions`.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("notification_container"));
```

Comment: Just reviewed the earlier tries from my end as I had already mentioned this in the note.. Even for the VisibilityOfElementLocated method I was passing By.className("notification_container"), "style", "display: block"
Changed it to just the locator... worked brilliantly !!

Comment: Any thoughts on why would attributesToBe and attributeContains methods fail this specific case??

Comment: My guess is that it's looking for an exact string match, e.g. "display: block; overflow: hidden; float: none" instead of just a substring but I don't think I've ever used `attributesToBe`. You'd have to look at the docs to see.